# Oracle Data Modeler trigger better representation

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, modeling

I am using *Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler* and it is a fantastic tool. When I try to represent a trigger interaction I can't find a respective element to do it. So I used a table reference with comments. But there is something tell me that is not de best way. How can I do it better?

The actual way:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure. It could be argued that a trigger (which moves data around and/or changes it) is not data but application logic and so should not be a part of a data model. Without knowing the details of what the trigger does to what and why, it's difficult to say more than that the diagram fragment you show looks to me to be a decent way of showing it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @simonatrcl. I agree!